# Create thumbnail from video at random time frame

Tags: bash, shell-script, ffmpeg

I'm using this bash script to generate thumbnails from videos:

```
#!/bin/bash
source_dir="."
output_dir="/output"
input_file_types=(avi wmv flv mkv mpg mp4)
output_file_type="jpg"
r1=$(( ( RANDOM % 10 )  + 5 ))

convert() {
        echo "" | ffmpeg -ss 00:"r1":05 -y -i "$1" -an -f image2 -vframes 1 "$output_dir/$2"
}

for input_file_type in "${input_file_types[@]}"
do
        find "$source_dir" -name "*.$input_file_type" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' in_file
        do
                echo "Processing…"
                echo ">Input  $in_file"

                # Replace the file type
                out_file=$(echo "$in_file" | sed "s/\(.*\.\)$input_file_type/\1$output_file_type/g")
                # The above can be shortened to
                # out_file="${in_file%.$input_file_type}.$output_file_type"
                echo ">Output $out_file"

                # Convert the file
                convert "$in_file" "$out_file"

                if [ $? != 0 ]
                then
                    echo "$in_file had problems" >> handbrake-errors.log
                fi

                echo ">Finished $out_file\n\n"
        done
done
echo "DONE CONVERTING FILES"
```

What I want is to calculate the total video time and generate a thumbnail from a random video time.

```
mediainfo myvideo.mp4 | grep Duration
Duration                                 : 5mn 7s
Duration                                 : 5mn 7s
Duration                                 : 5mn 7s
```

How do I integrate `grep Duration` into the bash script above so I can get a thumbnail with a random time based on the total video time?

Comment: I edited your question.  (1) If you’re going to pass arguments to a shell function, you should probably *use the arguments* rather than having the function access the global variables.  (2) `for bars in "${bars[@]}"` is not just stylistically confusing; it is like saying `for bars[0] in "${bars[@]}"`.  Not literally; that’s not syntactically valid; but my point is that it sets `bar[0]` equal to the last `bar[…]` value.  After your loop, `input_file_types` is equal to `( ` **`mp4 `** `wmv flv mkv mpg mp4)`.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  That could cause hard-to-debug problems if you ever used `"${input_file_types[@]}"` again in the script.  (3) You should always quote all shell variable references (e.g., `echo ">Input  "$in_file` → `echo ">Input  $in_file"`) unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re *sure* you know what you’re doing.  (4) Speaking of which, did you mean to say `ffmpeg -ss 00:"$r1":05`?

Answer (score 3):

Try grabbing the duration in seconds, as this will make everything easier:

Your convert function could end up being:

```
convert() {
    # Get duration in milliseconds, then convert to seconds
    duration=$(($(mediainfo --Inform="General;%Duration%" "${in_file}" ) / 1000 ))

    # Calculate random time
    random_time=$(date -u -d @$(shuf -i 0-${duration} -n 1) +"%T")

    # Take screenshot
    ffmpeg -ss ${random_time} -i "$in_file" -vframes 1 -q:v 2 "$output_dir/$output_file"
}
```

Comment: i got this error     Invalid duration specification for ss: -y

Comment: I fixed it up and tested it on my machine. ffmpeg can take the time in seconds, which removes a step.

Answer (score 0):

this bash will do

```
#!/bin/bash
source_dir="."
output_dir="."
input_file_types=(avi wmv flv mkv mpg mp4)
output_file_type="jpg"

convert() {
        echo "" | ffmpeg -ss $ss -y -i "$in_file" -an -f image2 -vframes 1 "$output_dir/$out_file"
}

for input_file_types in "${input_file_types[@]}"
do

        find "$source_dir" -name "*.$input_file_types" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' in_file
        do
                echo "Processing…"
                echo ">Input  "$in_file
                # Replace the file type
                out_file=$(echo $in_file|sed "s/\(.*\.\)$input_file_types/\1$output_file_type/g")
                echo ">Output "$out_file

    # get video duration
    fulltime=`ffmpeg -i "$in_file" 2>&1 | grep 'Duration' | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,//`;
    hour=`echo $fulltime | cut -d ':' -f 1`;
    minute=`echo $fulltime | cut -d ':' -f 2`;
    second=`echo $fulltime | cut -d ':' -f 3 | cut -d '.' -f 1`;

    seconds=`expr 3600 \* $hour + 60 \* $minute + $second`;
    ss=`expr $seconds / 2`; # from the middle of video

    # Convert the file
                convert "$in_file" "$out_file"

                if [ $? != 0 ]
                then
                    echo "$in_file had problems" >> ffmpeg-errors.log
                fi

                echo ">Finished "$out_file "\n\n"
        done
done
```

create thumbnail from middle of movie.

Answer (score 0):

Duration of the video:

```
DURATION=$(ffmpeg -i "$4" 2>&1 | grep "Duration"| cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,// | sed 's@\..*@@g' | awk '{ split($1, A, ":"); split(A[3], B, "."); print 3600*A[1] + 60*A[2] + B[1] }')
RES=$(ffmpeg -i "$4" 2>&1 | grep -oP 'Stream .*, \K[0-9]+x[0-9]+')
```

complete thumbnail-generator:
https://github.com/romanwarlock/thumbnails/blob/master/thumbgen.sh